# Teamspeak 3 Musicbot - Mute a user with only one identity

Tags: audio, streaming, audio-streaming, live-streaming, teamspeak

I am currently trying to setup a musicbot on a ts3 server (I´m NOT the owner of the server). I did that with the following software:

```
VB HiFi Audio Cable
Equalify Pro
Spotify
```

To get the musicbot on the ts3 server i just connect with a second identity. The problem is that the soundbot generates a huge echo when in an channel with several people. I tried muting the other people as the musicbot but then the ppl are muted on my normal identity too (which is bad when i still want to communicate with them). I´m not the server owner, so creating groups and editing channels isnt an option!

Is there a way to mute ppl for only ONE identity? So that the musicbot isnt able to hear the other ppl in a channel but I´m still able to talk with everybody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Music bot if you go to Settings > Options > Playback  > Go to your second Identity, perhaps named "Bot" if you followed the Matt&Haden turtorial for setting them up. The voice volume adjustment should be turned all the way down (make sure you click on the second identity first) aswell as the Sound Pack Volume should. The bot then should only play back what you want, an example is for me it plays back line 1 which my music runs off of.